# Beginner's question

Tags: regression, linear-regression

I am a beginner in ML, and I have data that look like a "cross" shape as follow:

[image]
[image]

It seems 2 regression lines are overlapped

Would you have any ideas for how to fit or predict y axis with x axis ?

Comment: You have only x as possible explanatory variable right? In this case you're probably stuck with linear regression, but it might not work very well.

Comment: I have actually 3 time series that produce this  ''cross'' shape, but with a different direction though

Comment: Time series, does that mean that x is time? If there are more details you can share in the question that could help getting answers.

Comment: Yep, need more info about variables/features to make something out of this